# How can I permanently cancel the "Sign in with your Apple ID" prompt?

Tags: apple-id

For the last couple of months my macbook air keeps getting a pop up in the top right corner that says I have to sign in again with my Apple ID or some services will not be available.

But everything works fine and I don't want to log in. So I hit the `x` to close the prompt.

The prompt itself is annoying because it covers the clock. What's also annoying is that upon closing the prompt the System Settings window pops up, on the Apple ID login screen. It also pops up over the window I'm working in already. It is basically a really intrusive vendor who just doesn't get the hint. Just stop man. Stop. Really.

It's confusing because I hit the `x`, why does it think I want to do something about it?

## question

Can I permanently disable the pop up?

If I ever need a service that requires Apple ID I can go log in. But I don't ever seem to need it.

Comment: Not sure it's the same context, but selecting to log in and then cancelling on the actual login screen sometimes seems to work.

Comment: @nohillside, I'll try that next time. Though... seems very similar to what I already do.

Comment: If I understood your question correctly, you currently try to cancel by closing (with the (x)) the notification on top right. The alternative would be to act on the notification (so you get to the actual login screen) and cancel there.

Comment: Happened again just now. I clicked the "view" button this time. That opens up the settings, there's no cancel button there. The "x" and "view" buttons have essentially the same functionality.

EDIT
I think I'll have to cave and just sign in. My surveillance capitalistic conspiracy theories be damned.